# How to Get the number of Folders from Mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

i am having a values in a database like followin

```
Field 2                             ! Field 2
----------------------------------------------
Rootfolder                          | v1
Rootfolder/subfolder1/            | v2
Rootfolder/subfolder1/subfolder2/ | v3    
Rootfolder2/subfolder1/subfolder2/ | v3
```

I want to get Resurlt set as

```
Root[name] =Rootfolder
Root[subfolder] = subfolder1,Subfolder2
```

I am using PHP as my server side. How can i get this result usign mysql or in PHP, can any one help this regards...

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, with your current structure:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(folder_field,'/',1) name
       SUBSTR(folder_field, LOCATE('/', folder_field) + 1) subfolder
  FROM table_name
 WHERE ...
```

Or, probably better, change your table to have a column for `name` and a column for `subfolder` and CONCAT where necessary.

.. or do it in PHP.

**UPDATE**

Given new information you could try:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(folder_field,'%5c',1) name
       SUBSTR(folder_field, LOCATE('%5c', folder_field) + 3) subfolder
  FROM table_name
 WHERE ...
```

Although I don't know how this works with SUBSTRING_INDEX

Comment: i am having seperator as %5c, How can i use in your Query.? if i use this , it consider only 5c only

Comment: @user3912844 See update, I also had the LOCATE params the wrong way round but have fixed it.

Comment: is there any way t avoid to consider"%" as a sql operator, when i am usign there it take as like operator

Comment: @user3912844 % is only considered a wildcard in LIKE, not in the functions I have provided.. if you need to escape it in a LIKE use \%